# How to apply transform() translate to a picture with float:left?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-transforms

So, I am just discovering the html/css programming world, and my goal is to ***align images side by side with a link in the middle***. Right now, I am trying with a text.

My problem is: I'm using `transform: translate();` for the text part, but if I `float:left` the image the text will stay in the center of the body instead of in the center of the image, and will be stackered.

Or is there a better way to do this?

***html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Twice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twices.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Twice</h1>

    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="nayeon.jpg" alt="nayeon" name="Nayeon">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text" style="color:#81d4fa">Nayon</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="jeongyeon.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text" style="color:#81d4fa">Jeongyeon</div>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

***css***

```
img{
    border-radius: 10%;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    margin: 0.5%;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.middle{
    transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  transform: translate(-590%, -250%);
}

.text{
    font-family: Lora;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

[example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uCU7.png)

---------------------------------------- update --------------------------------

I actually figured it out what I had to do. Putting it here if someone else needs it. It might seem silly but I was having a hard time with it.

Answer: the `float` property had to reach the image and the text so I transferred the `float:left` in the image to de div class that holds both the image and the text. Can't believe it was so simple.

***new html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Twice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twices.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Twice</h1>

    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="nayeon.jpg" alt="nayeon" name="Nayeon">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#81d4fa">Nayon</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="jeongyeon.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#aed581">Jeongyeon</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="momo.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#ffcdd2">Momo</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="sana.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#9fa8da">Sana</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="jihyo.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#ffb74d">Jihyo</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="mina.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#80cbc4">Mina</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="dahyun.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#ffffff">Dahyun</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="chaeyoung.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#ff1744">Chaeyoung</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="tzuyu.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="link" ><a href="" style="color:#0277bd">Tzuyu</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

***NEW CSS***

```
img{
    border-radius: 10%;
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
    margin: 0.5%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    color: white;
    float: left;/*--------- o float é no conteúdo todo--------------*/
}

.middle{
    /*transition: .5s ease;*/
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  transform: translate(-590%, -250%);
}

.link{
    font-family: Lora;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a diagram of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uCU7.png  --- I was trying to do this.

Comment: I see you managed to fix it yourself, do you need any more additional help?

Comment: no,  it was simple but I'm still a noob. thank you

Comment: Everyone is a noob to start off, best of luck with your coding journey! :)